# DB2 reset sequence midnight everyday

Tags: db2, sequence, reset, schedule

I need to auto reset a DB2 sequence every midnight .i have tried with admin tasks with sample i found in Example 1( https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0054371.html ).Even this got executed and show in systools.admin_task_list,It didn't reset sequence at midnight.
No items in systools.admin_task_status.how can I get errors related to admin tasks ?

Is there more easy way of resetting a DB2 sequence daily ?

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_TASK_ADD
  ('Reset_sales1_seq',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    '0 0 * * *',
    'SYSPROC',
    'ADMIN_CMD',
    'VALUES("ALTER SEQUENCE Sample.sales1_seq RESTART WITH 1")',
    NULL,
    NULL )
```

Comment: ... note that this sort of thing prevents you from going to full 24-hour sales, since transactions near the changeover point may end up with a mismatch between date and sequence number (potentially leading to duplicates - you're going to end up with holes in the sequence regardless).  You either need to switch to a table version keyed on your "business day" (quite often not strict server time), or to something like a GUID/UUID which doesn't need a strict sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using stored procedure `ADMIN_CMD` which only runs a specific selection of **commands**  as detailed in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0012547.html) .

Know the difference between plain SQL/DDL and commands.

`ADMIN_CMD` is not for running plain SQL statements directly like `ALTER SEQUENCE`.

Consider writing a simple stored-procedure to perform the `ALTER SEQUENCE` action in dynamic SQL, and then calling that procedure directly in the `ADMIN_TASK_ADD`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.RESET_SEQUENCE()
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('ALTER SEQUENCE SAMPLE.SALES1_SEQ RESTART WITH 1');
END
```

then

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_TASK_ADD
('Reset_sales1_seq',
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
NULL,
NULL,
'0 0 * * *',
'MYSCHEMA',
'RESET_SEQUENCE',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL )
```